# Custom tabbar items in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbar

I would like to create custom tabbar items similar to the ones shown here:

[image]

I assume these have to be designed and created first in Photoshop or a similar application. Are there any resources or tutorials available that demonstrate the creation of such items in Photoshop and how these are then used in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating and bundling bitmaps is one option - and likely the most common one (for which googling should turn up several tutorials). Now in order to get optimal quality you need to supply multiple sets for the *old* iPhone/iPod, the newer retina iPhone/iPod, the iPad (1,2) and the retina iPad 3.  This can takes a lot of space to cover each case with beautiful icons (or it won't look as good).

An **alternative** is to create the bitmaps at runtime, e.g. using the CoreGraphics API. This might seems counterproductive (and can surely be in many cases) but it has the advantage of requiring less (storage) space and/or getting better quality (see note).

Why ? because if you create them at runtime then you'll only create the ones for the specific device you're executing on. You can even cache them and re-create them when missing (e.g. if iOS flush your application cache).

If you're not an artist (and I'm not) you might want to look at easily licensable vector icons. The ones from your screenshot looks monochrome and could even use (bundle or extra the outlines from a) custom font - like the one provided by [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) (CC BY 3.0) or similar sources.

Note: Maybe you noticed (I know I did) that some iPad applications looked **beautiful** (compared to others) on the iPad3 even if they were released months before the hardware become available. Vector graphics wins ;-)

**UPDATE:** Someone already made a [script](https://github.com/jogloran/Font-Awesome) to convert the FontAwesome characters to iOS tab bar icons. However since it's done outside the app you'll need multiple versions of each bitmap to get the best look on every devices.